# set label text to span width with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, label

I want to set the specified label text to span width 
Here is the code. Thanks for your help.

```
function setBarWidth(labelText, barElement, cssProperty, barPercent) {
    var listData = [];
    $(labelText).each(function () {
        listData.push($(this).textContent);
    });
    var listMax = Math.max.apply(Math, listData);
    $(barElement).each(function(index) {
        $(this).css(cssProperty, (listData[index] / listMax) * barPercent + "%");
    });
}
setBarWidth(".style-1 span label", ".style-1 em", "width", 100);
setBarWidth(".style-2 span label", ".style-2 span", "width", 55);
```

Answer (score 1):

`textContent` is a DOM property, but `$(this)` is a jQuery object. You should use `this.textContent` or `$(this).text()`.

You can also replace `.each` with `.map`

```
var listData = $(labelText).map(function() {
    return this.textContent;
}).get();
```

`.get()` at the end is necessary to convert the jQuery collection into an ordinary array.